# Jmeter Performance Testing DOM and Load time

Tags: performance, testing, load, jmeter, performance-testing

1. What is the exact difference between DOM time and Page Load time. When I go to Google Chrome and Press F12 and go to Network, I see the DOM time and the Page Load Time and can this be implemented in Jmeter to get the DOM and Load time.
2. My second question is When I record my script in Jmeter and run it does each sample count as 1 Service as I need to run my website for 30,000 users.
3. Is the process same when performing uploading for some 10,000 products to ecommerce website and testing the performance of website, as uploading can be done using JDBC Insert command in Jmeter.

Answer (score 4):

1. The difference is:

   - `DOMContentLoaded` - HTML finished loading
   - `Loaded` - all other stuff finished loading (scripts, styles, images - everything pulled down by "Retrieve all embedded resources" option enabled). I would recommend to keep this option turned on as it makes JMeter behaviour closer to real life browsers. See [onLoad and onDOMContentLoaded](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded) and [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) articles for more information
2. It is unclear what do you mean by "Service". If you need to emulate 30 000 users - you need 30 000 threads. Make sure you use [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) as real user don't hammer application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between requests. Also most likely you will need more than one JMeter instance to simulate 30 000 users, check out [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) guide.

Comment: Thanks..we have to use distrubuted testing since on one machine JVM memory space is less.

Comment: Is the process same when performing uploading for some 10,000 products to ecommerce website and testing the performance of website, as uploading can be done using JDBC Insert command in Jmeter.